# Каково назначение ключа `-u` при git push?

Tags: git, git-push

И чем отличает отправка без ключа `git push origin master`.

Comment: Ответы в английской версии StackOverflow на аналогичный вопрос — http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697750/what-exactly-does-the-u-do-git-push-u-origin-master-vs-git-push-origin-ma — Вам понятны? Спасибо.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Если сделать `git push` ветки без ключа `-u`, Git не свяжет локальную ветку с веткой удалённого репозитория. Последующая операция `git pull` в этой ветке будет неудачной, так как Git не будет знать, из какой удалённой ветки подтягивать изменения, это придётся указать явно при помощи команды `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master`. Смысл использовать ключ `-u` есть только при пуше новых веток, для существующих (связанных с удалёнными) веток каждый раз перезаписывать связку необязательно.

Answer (score 14):

С ключом `-u` (полный вариант `--set-upstream`) вы создаёте (если ещё не существует) в удалённом репозитории ветку, соответствующую вашей локальной и связываете их:

- В remote/branchname будет производиться push в локальную ветку branchname
- Из remote/branchname будет производиться pull в локальную ветку branchname

Для `master` это актуально, только если вы пушите в пустой репозиторий. Если клонировали - то соответствие ветвей уже настроено. А вот как только вы создадите новую локальную ветвь и захотите её запушить на remote, вам понадобится ключ `-u`.

```
# есть у нас локальная ветка
git checkout -b mybranch

# Создаем ветку на remote
git push -u origin mybranch

# Можно выбрать другое имя для создаваемой ветки на remote.
git push -u origin mybranch_with_other_name
```