# Как клонировать проект?

Tags: git, git-clone

Допустим есть удалённая ветка с проектом под названием **project**, и мне нужно скопировать этот проект локально.
Я создал пустую папку, пусть **test-project**, в консоли ввожу

```
git init
```

находясь в этой папке. Потом в консоли ввожу

```
git clone http://bitbucket.org/project.git
```

В результате в папке test-project создаётся ещё одна папка **project** с проектом.
А мне нужно, чтобы проект скопировался в папку **test-project**, т.е. чтобы дополнительная папка project не создавалась, в которой есть также своя папка .git
Получается, что будет две папки .git(в папке **test-project** и в папке **project**)
Как правильно скопировать проект, чтобы потом можно было локальные изменения снова закинуть на удалённую ветку, закомитить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

git init при клонировании выполнять не нужно. Нужно просто правильно склонировать. Итак, удалите папку и ее содержимое и выполните такое

```
git clone http://bitbucket.org/project.git test-project
```

будет создана папка test-project и туда все склонировано.

Comment: а подскажите, после локальных редактирований кода, чтобы отправить изменения на удалённую ветку, нужно выполнить git push origin master  ? Нужен ли ключ -u   в этой команде?

Comment: думаю,, скорее всего Вам хватит просто git push. Но перед этим не забудьте git add и git commit

Comment: а объясните для полноты понимания работы с git, допустим я поработал с этим проектом test-project и сделал git push, потом кто-то другой внёс изменения на удалённую ветку. Как теперь обновить эти изменения на локальной ветке в клонированном проекте test-project ? т.е. как теперь из удалённой ветки скопировать изменения в локальную?

Comment: git pull origin ? правильно?

Comment: git pull будет достаточно. Но чтобы полностью ответить на предыдущий комментарий, мне нужно где то с часик рассказывать.

Comment: @word ключ `-u` нужен для того, чтобы git «запомнил» соответствие между вашей локальной веткой и веткой на сервере, куда вы пушите.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, а если этот проект создавался с ключом -u, а я после правок сделаю пуш (git push) без кюча -u, в проекте ничего не нарушится? т.е. гит все еще будет запоминать соответствие?

Comment: спрашиваю, потому что знаю, что проект создавался с ключом -u

Comment: @KoVadim, ничего не нарушится?

Comment: А как это проект "создавался с ключем -u"? может просто ветку привязали?

Comment: @word присоединяюсь к вопросу KoVadim. Фраза "проект создавался с ключом -u" совершенно непонятна. Репозиторий создается с помощью `git init` или `git clone`, а ключ этот с командой `push` используется.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, имелось ввиду, что при первом пуше (git push) использовался этот ключ -u.  Значит при последующих пушах можно этот ключ не указывать?

Comment: @word тут об этом подробно рассказано: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/498621/181472